# Cassandra not accepting messages over 800K out of 5Mil in 3 min

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark

I am facing an issue while inserting messages into Cassandra in a high volume/velocity scenario,. I have a Simulator which generates load of 5 Mil. Messages in 3 Minutes. The messages are landing into Kafka Topic, listened by a Spark RDD which then read records out from Kafka and insert them into Cassandra. The issue is that my Cassandra (single node installation) is not able to take messages beyond 800K and hangs(cannot see any log messages or movement on console)..

Following are some brief points relating to my deployment scheme:

- Cassandra-2.1.8 over Java--1.7.0_51-b13 on Ubuntu, is running on EC2 instance with 30 GBs of RAM and HDD
  30GBs.
- Spark is pushing message size of 2 KBs of JSON.
- Spark is running on a separate EC2 instance and so is Simulator.

Below is the YAML configuration file for my Cassandra instance:

- num_tokens: 256
- hinted_handoff_enabled: true
- max_hint_window_in_ms: 10800000
- hinted_handoff_throttle_in_kb: 1024
- max_hints_delivery_threads: 2
- batchlog_replay_throttle_in_kb: 1024
- authenticator: AllowAllAuthenticator
- authorizer: AllowAllAuthorizer
- permissions_validity_in_ms: 2000
- partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur
- Partitioner disk_failure_policy: stop
- commit_failure_policy: stop
- key_cache_size_in_mb:
- key_cache_save_period: 14400
- row_cache_size_in_mb: 0
- row_cache_save_period: 0
- counter_cache_size_in_mb:
- counter_cache_save_period: 7200
- commitlog_sync: periodic
- commitlog_sync_period_in_ms: 10000
- commitlog_segment_size_in_mb: 32
- seed_provider:
- - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
- concurrent_reads: 32
- concurrent_writes: 64
- concurrent_counter_writes:32
- memtable_allocation_type: heap_buffers
- index_summary_capacity_in_mb:
- index_summary_resize_interval_in_minutes: 60
- trickle_fsync: false
- trickle_fsync_interval_in_kb: 10240
- storage_port: 7000
- ssl_storage_port: 7001
- listen_address: ec2-XXX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
- broadcast_address: ec2-XXX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
- start_native_transport: true
- native_transport_port: 9042
- start_rpc: true
- rpc_address: ec2-XXX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
- rpc_port: 9160
- broadcast_rpc_address: ec2-XXX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
- rpc_keepalive: true
- rpc_server_type: sync
- thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb: 15
- incremental_backups: false
- snapshot_before_compaction: false
- auto_snapshot: true
- tombstone_warn_threshold: 1000
- tombstone_failure_threshold: 100000
- column_index_size_in_kb: 64
- batch_size_warn_threshold_in_kb: 5
- compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec: 16
- compaction_large_partition_warning_threshold_mb: 100
- sstable_preemptive_open_interval_in_mb: 50
- read_request_timeout_in_ms: 10000
- range_request_timeout_in_ms: 50000
- write_request_timeout_in_ms: 5000
- counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms: 5000
- cas_contention_timeout_in_ms: 1000
- truncate_request_timeout_in_ms:60000
- request_timeout_in_ms: 10000
- cross_node_timeout: false
- endpoint_snitch: SimpleSnitch
- dynamic_snitch_update_interval_in_ms: 100
- dynamic_snitch_reset_interval_in_ms: 600000
- dynamic_snitch_badness_threshold: 0.1
- request_scheduler: org.apache.cassandra.scheduler.NoScheduler
- server_encryption_options:
     internode_encryption: none
     keystore: conf/.keystore
     keystore_password: cassandra
     truststore: conf/.truststore
     truststore_password: cassandra client_encryption_options:
     enabled: false
     keystore: conf/.keystore
     keystore_password: cassandra internode_compression: all
- inter_dc_tcp_nodelay: false

I deeply appreciate your time to help resolve this issue. please let me know what all information you need and I shall post that as well..

Regards
Rohit Anand

Comment: It sounds likely that you are running out of memory. What is your Cassandra-env look like? And what is the data model of the table being  written too?

Comment: not able to post the complete file because of comment limitation, please let me know specific lines or snippets and I shall post them

Comment: domainid uuid,messagearrivaltimestamp timestamp,messageid uuid,rawmessage text, PRIMARY KEY (domainid, messagearrivaltimestamp))

Comment: (messagearrivaltimestamp ASC)AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01 AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL","rows_per_partition":"NONE"}' AND comment = '' AND compaction ={'class':org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'} AND compression ={'sstable_compression':'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'} AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1 AND default_time_to_live = 0 AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000 AND max_index_interval = 2048 AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0 AND min_index_interval = 128 AND read_repair_chance = 0.0 AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE'

Comment: Ok. Output from nodetool info will do

Comment: ID                     : 9c25c24f-1c1b-4f32-80a6-6e6fe6cc9a9b
Gossip active          : true
Thrift active          : true
Native Transport active: true
Load                   : 115.23 MB
Generation No          : 1442810579
Uptime (seconds)       : 969
Heap Memory (MB)       : 2750.69 / 10137.63
Off Heap Memory (MB)   : 1.89
Data Center            : datacenter1
Rack                   : rack1
Exceptions             : 0

Comment: Key Cache              : entries 81, size 7.64 KB, capacity 100 MB, 64 hits, 356 requests, 0.180 recent hit rate, 14400 save period in seconds
Row Cache              : entries 0, size 0 bytes, capacity 0 bytes, 0 hits, 0 requests, NaN recent hit rate, 0 save period in seconds
Counter Cache          : entries 0, size 0 bytes, capacity 50 MB, 0 hits, 0 requests, NaN recent hit rate, 7200 save period in seconds
Token                  : (invoke with -T/--tokens to see all 256 tokens)

Comment: I think it might be in the volume of the payload all getting pushed at one machine. On JSON payloads, I recommend compressing at the client level and storing in a blob. Turn off compression for the table bring insert to and save some CPU. I would also watch the JVM on loading.

Comment: okay.. my payload is already compressed. let me change the table structure to put payload data into a blob type column. I'll also try to optimize Java memory and change heap size params. will post my findings.. Thanks Patrick for your time, I appreciate that..:-)

Comment: well.. I upgraded Cassandra from 2.1.8 to 2.1.9 and it started to take my load without any exception. I am was able to load 10 Mil messages of 2 KBs in 10 Mins through Spark.. so it seems there is some known issue which was fixed in the later release... anyways

Answer (score 0):

well.. I upgraded Cassandra from 2.1.8 to 2.1.9 and it started to take my load without any exception. my kept the same environment and was able to load 10 Mil. messages of 2 KBs in 10 Mins. through Spark.. so it seems there is some known issue which got fixed in the later release...